# Is there a one-word synonym for "unwelcome surprise"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Or anything along the lines of that (unpleasant surprise amounts to about the same thing). As in,

> *He/She found an unwelcome surprise waiting for them.*

Unwelcome/unpleasant surprise would work in this context, but I feel I have used it too often, and need a change.

Thank you!

Comment: You might be unnecessarily boxing yourself into a corner by asking for a *noun*. Particularly, to identify something that might be metaphorically "waiting for them" (within which context the otherwise perfectly reasonable ***bolt from the blue*** and ***rude awakening*** wouldn't work very well). But I think this is really "writing advice" with no clearly identifiable "correct" answer (a ***bombshell*** might work, though).

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you'd suggested bombshell before posting.  It seems worthy of being an answer though. While single-word-requests don't usually have "correct" answers, they're still welcome at ESE though, yes?

Comment: There are several options  (I think @Kris may have meant "start") but nothing generally useful. Each is good in a specific context.

Comment: Start. >a sudden movement of surprise or alarm. "she awoke with a start" synonyms: jerk, twitch, flinch, wince, spasm, convulsion, jump "she awoke with a start"

Comment: Thanks @itsbruce  I deleted the other post misspell start with an h as second letter is a slang expression that is ironic as an answer to this question lol

Answer (score 7):

Consider [*shock* (Oxford Learner’s Dictionary):](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/shock_1?q=shock)

> [countable, usually singular, uncountable] a strong feeling of surprise as a result of something happening, especially something unpleasant; the event that causes this feeling

As you have a number of “unwelcome surprises” in your text I would reserve *shock* for the really bad ones. Here are some examples of actual use (my boldface):

> Prokofiev had **a shock waiting for him** in Chicago regarding *Oranges*. After arriving in town on 31 October he wrote to Johnson requesting a meeting to settle their disagreement "peacefully." The letter he received in return on 2 November did not contain anything about an appointment, rather it bore the news that two weeks ago a telegram had been sent to him in France stating that *Oranges* had been canceled permanently.
>   [[Stephen D. Press, *Prokofiev’s Ballets for Diaghilev*, 2006.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4Uqv0uLX7dwC&pg=PA44&dq=%22shock%20waiting%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6tJyox9XOAhVBvBQKHfUNBzcQ6AEIgAEwEQ#v=onepage&q=%22shock%20waiting%20for%22&f=false)
>
> Our return to England was homecoming in many ways, but there was **a shock waiting for me** when we reached the hotel at Rye. I was handed a cablegram: “Don't come home. I am in good hands. Mother.” The rest of the day was frantic. Heart Attack? Stroke? Paralysis?
>   [[Doris McCarthy, *Doris McCarthy: My Life*, 2006.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HAUvDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT112&dq=%22shock%20waiting%20for%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6tJyox9XOAhVBvBQKHfUNBzcQ6AEIcDAO#v=onepage&q=%22shock%20waiting%20for%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

**Bombshell** — [(Cambridge)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bombshell)

> a sudden and often unpleasant piece of news:

works well (he/she found a bombshell awaiting him/her), as do many other [synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/shock) of shock (such as [stunner](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stunner), [jolt](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jolt), [whammy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whammy)), However, as Jacinto noted, they are best reserved for larger surprises.

Other words explaining the emotions or style of disrupt may be more helpful to exchange out more regular surprises, such as [snafus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snafu), [complications](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/complication), or [strangeness](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strangeness).

Answer (score 0):

***Vicissitude*** may or may not work with what you’re trying to express. This is a bit after the fact but thought it may help you or someone looking.

> changes that happen at different times during the life or development of someone or something, especially those that result in conditions being worse:

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vicissitudes)